# Using schema for Procedure on @NamedStoredProcedureQuery in Spring 4 JPA Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm get stuck with how i can using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery with schema in Entity for my Service.For example i have a shema call "appschema" and my store procedure base on another schema like "dbschema",i have create the same proc in my default schema everything work fine but when i try to using procedureName = "dbschema.myStoreName" it's not understand. So anybody can help!
Thanks for yours help.

This is my Entities:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "TestProc", procedureName = "appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO", 
    resultClasses = {
        ProcGetAccounts.class }, parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pm_id", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pm_acct", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pm_acct_name", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pm_acct_type", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pm_curr", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pm_date", type = Date.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "p_err", type = Float.class, mode = ParameterMode.OUT),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "p_ref_cur", type = void.class, mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR) })
public class ProcGetAccounts implements Serializable{...}
```

this is the error:

```
03-11-2018 11:06:51  DEBUG  (http-nio-8866-exec-2)  
    {call appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
Hibernate: 
    {call appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
03-11-2018 11:06:51  DEBUG  (http-nio-8866-exec-2)  Stored procedure [appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO] IN/INOUT parameter [org.hibernate.procedure.internal.NamedParameterRegistration@2e3edb84] not bound and `passNulls` was set to false; assuming procedure defines default value
03-11-2018 11:06:51  DEBUG  (http-nio-8866-exec-2)  Stored procedure [appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO] IN/INOUT parameter [org.hibernate.procedure.internal.NamedParameterRegistration@735676a9] not bound and `passNulls` was set to false; assuming procedure defines default value
03-11-2018 11:06:51  DEBUG  (http-nio-8866-exec-2)  Stored procedure [appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO] IN/INOUT parameter [org.hibernate.procedure.internal.NamedParameterRegistration@7485f578] not bound and `passNulls` was set to false; assuming procedure defines default value
03-11-2018 11:06:51  DEBUG  (http-nio-8866-exec-2)  Stored procedure [appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO] IN/INOUT parameter [org.hibernate.procedure.internal.NamedParameterRegistration@1cb9b23c] not bound and `passNulls` was set to false; assuming procedure defines default value
03-11-2018 11:06:51  DEBUG  (http-nio-8866-exec-2)  Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO]
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'appSchema.P_GET_ACCOUNT_INFO' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:205) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1043) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4755) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:52) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:32) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:411) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:363) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at com.dab.ptud.spring.ws.app.access.CollateralAccountsDaoImpl.getCollateralAccountsByTaxCode(CollateralAccountsDaoImpl.java:60) [classes/:?]
    at com.dab.ptud.spring.ws.app.access.CollateralAccountsDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d256a02e.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.dab.ptud.spring.ws.app.access.CollateralAccountsDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43f5a35a.getCollateralAccountsByTaxCode(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at com.dab.ptud.spring.ws.app.business.CollateralAccountsBoImpl.getCollaterallAccountsByTaxCode(CollateralAccountsBoImpl.java:44) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.getCollaterallAccountsByTaxCode(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.dab.ptud.spring.ws.app.services.BaseServicesImpl.HandlerMsg(BaseServicesImpl.java:190) [classes/:?]
    at com.dab.ptud.spring.ws.app.endpoint.SpringWebserviceEndPoint.callExecution(SpringWebserviceEndPoint.java:46) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:291) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:55) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:236) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293) [spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_102]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problems that i have to permitted my app schema to can execute Proc in another schema. I'm using Oracle Database.

Comment: would you please help me follow up this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848271/oracle9i-jpa-hibernate-namedstoredprocedurequery-string-attributes-of-my-objec